# ADC reference voltage for nRF52840

Tags: voltage, adc, voltage-divider, thermistor, nrf52832

[image]

I have designed an voltage divider bias with thermistor and the output voltage is given to adc pin of my nRF. But the internal reference voltage of my nRF is 3.6V so I did not get any accurate values and also , i cannot supply 5V as reference as it may damage the board. 
Is it possible to convert 5V to 3.6V and give it as supply to voltage divider of thermistor.
Any other suggestions please tell me !!! 
Thanks

Comment: You haven't demonstrated that you have designed anything yet until you have values for R0 and limit values for Rt with design formulas and evidence that they produce a voltage at the midpoint that is representative of what you want.

Comment: Value of R0 = 10Kohms and thermistor 10kohms at 25 degree celcius

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. What is the value of Vs? Assuming I understand correctly that it is 5V, then the bias point of your voltage divider at room temperature is 2.5V, which is within the range of your nRF reference of 3.6V.

Comment: Actually I solved the problem by giving 3V from vdd , thus ensuring the desired Vs for my Vref